# How to accumulate all values inside a 2D array that share the same field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a 2D array that contains values like this:

```
var array = [["10/10/2020","1000"],["10/10/2020","300"],["07/10/2020","100"],["07/10/2020","100"],["03/10/2020","100"],["10/10/2020","100"]];
```

For every nested array that has the same date value (the first element), I want to add up the second value to have something like this:

```
arrayAdd = [["10/10/2020","1400"],["O7/10/2020","200"],["03/10/2020","100"]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [["10/10/2020","1000"],["10/10/2020","300"],["07/10/2020","100"],["07/10/2020","100"],["03/10/2020","100"],["10/10/2020","100"]];

function fromEntries (iterable) {
  return [...iterable].reduce((obj, [key, val]) => {
    obj[key] = String(obj[key] ? +obj[key] + +val : val)
    return obj
  }, {})
}

console.log(fromEntries(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

1. Create an empty object/map.
2. Iterate over your array.

   Get the first element of each item in the array (date) and check if that key is already in the object.

   - If it is not, you add it. The value will be the second element (the number).
   - If it is there already, you increment the value.
3. [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will turn that object into an array with the shape you want, as you can see below:

```js
const obj = {
  "10/10/2020": "1400",
  "O7/10/2020": "200",
  "03/10/2020": "100",
};

console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to handle this question.

You can either compare the string values of each date to see if they are the same, or you can convert them to date objects and compare them that way. [Here's a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) to the MDN document that shows how you can get a primitive value for the date.

I'm going to use the string value because, in this case, I'm going to assume that all dates are coming in a consistent format.

```
let array = [["10/10/2020","1000"],["10/10/2020","300"],["07/10/2020","100"],["07/10/2020","100"],["03/10/2020","100"],["10/10/2020","100"]];
let arrayAdd = []
for (let valuePair of array) {
  // grab just the date value
  let date = valuePair[0];
  // check to see if pair is in arrayAdd 
  let foundPair = arrayAdd.find(el => el[0] === date)
  // will return undefined if nothing found
  if (!foundPair) {
     // if nothing found, we push the entire value and date pair
     arrayAdd.push(valuePair);
  } else {
     // few things happening here.. 
     // we have to convert each value to number to properly add
     // once they're added, we convert that new value back into a string
     // and then set the value of the found pair to that new string.
     foundPair[1] = (Number(valuePair[1]) + 
     Number(foundPair[1])).toString();
  }
}
console.log(arrayAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```js
const data = [["10/10/2020","1000"],["10/10/2020","300"],["07/10/2020","100"],["07/10/2020","100"],["03/10/2020","100"],["10/10/2020","100"]];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((res, [key, value] ) => {
  return {
    ...res,
    [key]: (res[key] || 0) + Number(value)
  }

}, {}))

console.log(result)
```